# Speed up slow meteor.js build times

Tags: meteor

The time it takes to bundle even the trivial, hundred line, demo apps in Meteor is about twenty five seconds.  This seems very slow to me.  Is there a way of speeding this up quite drastically?

I'm a newbie to Meteor.  It was pointed out to me as I was looking for a way of speeding up development and indeed getting changes out live is great but the code and test cycle is much slower than I'm used to.  There is only so much coffee I can drink whilst waiting. :-)

I'm running on a Macbook Pro, i7, 8G RAM or a quad core Xeon server (8 with hyperthreading).  The run times are similar.  No shortage of umph there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it takes a while, but you should only be bundling when you are ready to push your changes to a production environment. When developing your app you should just run `meteor` from your app's root directory, and open your browser to `http://localhost:3000`. In development mode, any changes your make to your code will be immediately reflected in your browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've got a larger app.  With my app, even that 'immediate' update itself takes 30-60s. This is killing my development time.  I've tried basically reinstalling everything. I can't readily move all of the application into packages.  Are there other ways to try to fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem as @user2330237. Every time I save, there's a long slow wait for meteor to seemingly rebuild *everything* before I get a chance to see the results. And I thought Django was slow!

Comment: Agreed. It's unrelated to the original question, but meteor has become painfully slow since the new packaging system was introduced. The good news is the core devs are actively working on a solution. Hopefully we'll see a big improvement in an upcoming release (1.2.x?).

Comment: Nope.  Twice as bad.

Comment: @user2330237 what machine specs are you using ?

Comment: @Rikki what machine specs are you using?

Comment: @DavidWeldon what machine specs are you using?

Comment: @MichaelCole what machine specs are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ecmascript and jsx packages you can replace them with [universe:ecmascript](https://atmospherejs.com/universe/ecmascript).

It should help in meteor 1.2, because universe:ecmascript uses new cache compiler instead babel cache. Difference is in storing cache files (babel use only disk and cache compiler additionally uses ram cache.)