# Update remote Meteor app on the go

Tags: javascript, meteor

so I'm creating this app using Meteor, and I deployed it on my own server using the bundle method (making the bundle, upload it to the server, extract it, recompiling native packages then launching it with Node).

The problem is that I'll have to do that whenever I change one line of code (doing that for adding a 1px in css seems crazy..)

Is there a way to update my app without going through all this ?

Comment: have meteor development mode is not an option, have you tried `meteor --production`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Speed up slow meteor.js build times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936242/speed-up-slow-meteor-js-build-times)

Comment: I don't think you got me guys. I'm looking for a way to update my app without having to bundle each time..

Comment: I understand that, but you haven't told us why that is needed. If you are developing, then development or `--production` mode seem more appropriate. You can still run on port 80 and so on if that's the concern.

Comment: Ok let me put it in other words:

1- I'm developping the app on my local machine, then I'm deploying it on my remote server.
2- in order to deploy it on my remote server (for production) I have to bundle the app, upload the bundle via ftp, extract it, reinstall Fiber, kill previous instance of Node, then launch the new version with Node.

I'm looking into this, because making all those steps each time I change something seems counter productive, I can make a script for all this, but I'm looking for a "magical" way if it exists, same magical way as "meteor deploy myapp.meteor.com"